# Solr - Suggester custom field not detected & Multiple fields cannot work

Tags: solr

**Goal**

Trying to implement an auto-suggester in Solr. Fields to extra suggestions from are `title` and `content` fields.

**Progress thus far**

I followed the official Solr guide to implement the feature, however, was stuck for a long time, as it was complaining that the custom field `suggestType` was not defined.

After a long time of trying I decided to add the field type to **managed-schema.xml** instead of **schema.xml** and it worked!

Thus far, it only worked when I based the suggestion field off `content`, however, we would like to use 2 fields to base suggestions of which is `title` and `content`.

**Steps followed**

1) Add custom field type in **managed-schema** xml:

```
<fieldType name="suggestType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]" replacement=" " />
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

2) Add custom field which uses custom field type in **schema.xml**:

```
<field name="suggestText" type="suggestType" stored="true" indexed="true" />
```

3) Add 'suggest' handler in **solr-config.xml**:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">fuzzySuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="storeDir">fuzzy_suggestions</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">suggestText</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">suggestType</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="suggest">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.dictionary">analyzingSuggester</str>
        <str name="suggest.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
        <str name="suggest.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

4) Copy both fields 'title' and 'content' to 'suggestText' in **schema.xml**:

```
<copyField source="title" dest="suggestField"/>
<copyField source="content" dest="suggestField"/>
```

**Questions**

- Why does it only work when I add the custom field type to **managed-schema.xml** instead of **schema.xml**? From my understanding, **managed-schema.xml** should not be manually edited.
- No results seem to appear when after I map both `title` and `content` field to the custom field `textSuggest`. I would like to know what I am missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a typo in your copy-field definition. The "dest" attribute is **suggestField** but the field you created earlier is called **suggestText**.